# Filter out numbers in a string in php

Tags: php

assuming i have these texts 'x34' , '150px' , '650dpi' , 'e3r4t5' ... how can i get only numbers ? i mean i want 34 , 150 , 650 , 345 without any other character . i mean get the numbers this string has into one variable .

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sorry for joining the bandwagon late, rather than using Regex, I would suggest you use PHP's built in functions, which may be faster than Regex.

[filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

[flags for the filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php)

e.g. to get just numbers from the given string

```
<?php
$a = '!a-b.c3@j+dk9.0$3e8`~]\]2';
$number = str_replace(['+', '-'], '', filter_var($a, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));
// Output is 390382
?>
```

To adhere to more strict standards for your question, I have updated my answer to give a better result.

I have added str_replace, as `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT` or `INT` flag will not strip `+` and `-` chars from the string, because they are part of PHP's exception rule.

Though it has made the filter bit long, but it's now has less chance of failing or giving you unexpected results, and this will be faster than REGEX.

**Edit:**

**1:** Realized that with `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT`, PHP won't strip these characters *optionally* `.,eE`, hence to get just pure numbers kindly use `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT`

**2:** If you have a PHP version less than **5.4**, then kindly use `array('+', '-')` instead of the short array syntax `['+', '-']`.

Comment: For those who want to simply return "false" if it's not an int, use the FILTER_VALIDATE_INT filter instead.

Answer (score 26):

```
$str = "e3r4t5";
$str_numbers_only = preg_replace("/[^\d]/", "", $str);

// $number = (int) $str;
```

Comment: why don't use PHP filter functions from now on, which is recommended. Please find my answer below

Answer (score 13):

You can use a regular expression to remove any character that is not a digit:

```
preg_replace('/\D/', '', $str)
```

Here the pattern `\D` describes any character that is not a digit (complement to `\d`).

Answer (score 11):

Use PHP FILTER functions if you are using PHP 5.2.X, 5.3.x,5.4 . Its highly recommended

```
$mixed_input = "e3r4t5";
$only_numbers = filter_var($mixed_input, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Please Go through with [this link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) to know more

Comment: I agree this is recommended. However it could not work as expected if the mixed_input contains '+' or '-' signs, since these are not filtered out, even in the middle of the string.

Answer (score 4):

Replace everything that isn't a number and use that value.

```
$str = "foo1bar2baz3";
$num = intval(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $str));
```

Comment: I guess the above answer is more efficient, considering the usage on millions of entities.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following function:

```
function extract_numbers($string)  {
  preg_match_all('/([\d]+)/', $string, $match);
  return $match;
}
```