# Filter between characters of string in PHP

Tags: php, string, split

I have a string like this: 12PUM4

It has two to three numbers at the beginning, it has three characters in the middle and it has one to two numbers at the end.

I want to split it somehow into three section:

1. the numbers until the characters
2. the characters from the middle
3. the rest behind the characters.

Can someone help please?

Comment: you need to use `explode` with some `regex` http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Comment: The problem is I haven't used regex before, so I thought some could help in more depth.

Comment: Links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837278/filter-out-numbers-in-a-string-in-php

Comment: No need to use explode. You cant use explode without a delimiter. No need to use regex either, as they are complex :P . Look at my answer, the easy way to do it ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [preg_match()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php);

```
$str = '12PUM4';
$matches = array();
preg_match('/([0-9]+)([a-zA-z]+)(.*)/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output**

```
Array ( [0] => 12PUM4 [1] => 12 [2] => PUM [3] => 4 )
```

when you use this function it will split text and put matches in `$matches` array

- `[0-9]+` - matches for numbers at least one or more
- `[a-zA-Z]+` are characters at least one or more
- `.*` is anything(almost)
- `()` - is used as subpattern which is put into `$matches` array

More information of how to use preg_match can be found [here](https://www.php.net/preg_match)

The solution with **substr()** under condtion you wrote that it has 12 digits, 3 characters and 1 or 2 digits in the end.

```
$str = '12PUM4';
$matches = array( 0 => substr($str,0, 2), 1 => substr($str, 2, 3) , 2 => substr($str, 5, strlen($str)>6 ? 2 : 1));
print_r($matches);
```

**Output**

```
Array ( [0] => 12 [1] => PUM [2] => 4 )
```

Answer (score 1):

[sscanf()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) would also be an option here:

```
$input = '12PUM4'; 
$splitValues = sscanf('%d%[A-Z]%d', $input); 
var_dump($splitValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the regular expression

```
$string = '12PUM4';
$array = preg_split('#(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)#i', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$name = "12PUM4"
$pattern = "/^([0-9]{2,3})([A-Z]{3})([0-9]{1,2})$/";
preg_match($pattern, $name , $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // first numbers
echo $matches[2]; // middle chars
echo $matches[3]; // last numbers
```

Comment: It will show either 2,3 numbers 3 characters and 1 or 2 numbers at end. Read the question because he asked for example "the numbers until the characters"

Comment: `It has two to three numbers at the beginning, it has three characters in the middle and it has one to two numbers at the end.` did you read that part of question? btw thx for your `not useful` vote :)

Comment: Okay you're right but he also wrote "the numbers until the characters
the characters from the middle
the rest behind the characters." anyway I'll cancel downvote.

Comment: it's ok and my solution is right, its output : `Array ( [0] => 12PUM4 [1] => 12 [2] => PUM [3] => 4 )`, whats wrong with that?

Comment: small chars are easy part of the question, just add `i` at the end of the pattern :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '12PUM4';

$strCnt = strlen($string);
$tmpStr = '';
$conArr = array();
for($i=0;$i<$strCnt;$i++){
    if(is_numeric($string[$i])){
        if($tmpStr != '' && !is_numeric($tmpStr)){
            $conArr[] = $tmpStr;
            $tmpStr = '';
        }
        $tmpStr .= $string[$i]; 
    }else{
        if(is_numeric($tmpStr)){
            $conArr[] = $tmpStr;
            $tmpStr = '';
        }
        $tmpStr .= $string[$i]; 
    }
}
$conArr[] = $tmpStr;

print_r($conArr);
```