# how to get numerals from the string in php

Tags: php, string

i have searched through the internet but i couldn't find a solution to my problem. 
I have a string which contain numeric values , i want to get these numeric values and store them each in a different variable.

**here is my string**

```
$string = "WALIOFANYA MTIHANI : 70 
WASTANI WA SHULE : 138.2571 
NAFASI YA SHULE KIWILAYA: 25 kati ya 125 
NAFASI YA SHULE KIMKOA : 117 kati ya 571 
NAFASI YA SHULE KITAIFA : 1249 kati ya 15656 ";
```

**output i want**

```
$v1 = 70
$v2 = 138.2571
$v3 = 25
$v4 = 125
$v5 = 117
$v6 = 571
$v7 = 1249
$v8 = 15656
```

i tried to use `stristr()`  and `substr()` but i failed;

is this even possible? if so how can i do this?

any help please.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837278/filter-out-numbers-in-a-string-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string = "WALIOFANYA MTIHANI : 70 
WASTANI WA SHULE : 138.2571 
NAFASI YA SHULE KIWILAYA: 25 kati ya 125 
NAFASI YA SHULE KIMKOA : 117 kati ya 571 
NAFASI YA SHULE KITAIFA : 1249 kati ya 15656 ";

preg_match_all('#([0-9.]+)#is', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Comment: then this would be wrong with text: `chapter 6.4.3` you would catch this too :p

Answer (score 1):

You can use preg_split:

```
$result = preg_split('~(?:[^\d.]++|(?<!\d)\.)+~', $str, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
preg_match_all('/\((\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\)/', $str, $matches)
```

should work for you where

```
$str = "WALIOFANYA MTIHANI : 70 
WASTANI WA SHULE : 138.2571 
NAFASI YA SHULE KIWILAYA: 25 kati ya 125 
NAFASI YA SHULE KIMKOA : 117 kati ya 571 
NAFASI YA SHULE KITAIFA : 1249 kati ya 15656 ";
```

the code goes as:

```
if (preg_match_all('/\((\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\)/', $str, $matches) > 0) {
        var_dump($matches[1]);
    }
```

Comment: Why use a such complicated regexp to match numbers?