# Group values of a flat array based on their leading substring

Tags: php, arrays, grouping, string-parsing, delimited

What I want the code below to do is loop through the `$check_query` array, find all the values that contain the word standard and push them into an array. I'd like to also do this for the strings that contain upgrade.
Example $range_array should return ['standard-186', 'standard-184];

```
$check_query = ['standard-186', 'upgrade-186', 'standard-184', 'upgrade-184'];
$range_array = [];
$spec_array = [];

foreach($check_query as $value) {

    if (in_array("standard", $value)) {
        array_push($range_array, $value);
    }
    elseif (in_array("upgrade", $value)) {
        array_push($spec_array, $value);
    } else {
        // Nothing
    }
}

echo $range_array;
echo $spec_array;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in one line using `array_filter()`

```
<?php

$check_query = ['standard-186', 'upgrade-186', 'standard-184', 'upgrade-184'];

$value = "standard";

$range_array = array_filter($check_query, function($a) use($value){return (stripos($a, $value)!==false);});
print_r($range_array);
```

Output

```
Array ( [0] => standard-186 [2] => standard-184 )
```

For `$spec_array` do the same thing with a different value for `$value`.

For PHP 8 you can use `str_contains()` instead of `stripos()`:

```
$res = array_filter($check_query, function($a) use($value){return str_contains($a, $value);});
print_r($res);
```

Comment: Your first solution works great. With that output would I now be able to take that array and remove all words in the strings and just keep the numbers?

Comment: @monsaic123 It's just an array. You can do what you like with it.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular `print_r($res);` --$res not defined. =)

Comment: @monsaic123 You can now use f.e. regex to filter numbers from the strings in the new array. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837278/filter-out-numbers-in-a-string-in-php/13287725 .

Comment: BTW; array_map does the job f.e.: `$array = array_map(function ($str) {return preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $str);}, $array);`

Comment: BTW, `preg_replace()` doesn't need `array_map()` to help it access all values.  `[^\d]` equals `\D`.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop, `$value` contains a string, so you have to check if your string is a part of that string.

```
$check_query = ['standard-186', 'upgrade-186', 'standard-184', 'upgrade-184'];
$range_array = [];
$spec_array = [];

foreach($check_query as $value) {

    if (strpos($value,"standard") !== false) {
        array_push($range_array, $value);
    }
    elseif (strpos($value,"upgrade") !== false) {
        array_push($spec_array, $value);
    } else {
        // Nothing
    }
}
```

Outputs:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I gave that a try. echo $range_array gave me: standard-186,upgrade-186,standard-184,upgrade-184. I need it to just contain strings with the word 'standard'

Comment: No, I tested in my end and it worked perfectly as expected. what is your PHP version?

Comment: My php version 7.3.5

Comment: Mine is 7.1. This should work. I will add my outputs to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It probably isn't advantages to declare two separate output variables.  To separate the data into two groups, just isolate the letter before the delimiter in each string and push the value into that group/subarray.

In your comment under another answer, you asked to only store the numeric portion in each group.  `sscanf()` is the perfect tool to parse each string and return the two parts. By using `%d` in the format parameter, the numeric substring will be cast as an integer.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/pGv1a))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($check_query as $v) {
    [$group, $result[$group][]] = sscanf($v, '%[^-]-%d');
    #        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-push number into group's subarray
    #^^^^^^-isolate leading string as a temporary variable
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'standard' => 
  array (
    0 => 186,
    1 => 184,
  ),
  'upgrade' => 
  array (
    0 => 186,
    1 => 184,
  ),
)
```